# GoogleApiClient - UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE(8050)

Tags: android, google-api-client, google-nearby

I'm calling GoogleApiClient into a Service.  The first time the service is launched, **onConnected()** is called.  Then the service is stopped via **stopSelf()** and restarted so mGoogleApiClient (null) is build again:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addApi(Nearby.CONNECTIONS_API)
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.build();
```

then :

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect()
```

result :

> NearbyDiscoveryService: onConnectionFailed :: ConnectionResult{statusCode=UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE(8050), resolution=null, message=null}

Any idea what's the problem ?  Google tells nothing about error code 8050 (related to Android) !

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem.  I must close the GoogleApiClient's connection before calling **stopSelf()**:

```
//[...]

if( isDiscovering() ) {
    stopDiscovering();
}

if (!isAdvertising()) {
    getGoogleApiClient().disconnect();
    stopSelf();
}

//[...]
```